# Provide common props interface across similar React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of similar components, they should all accept a list of properties common between them all, along with component-specific ones. For sake of terseness I'm going to list two, but the real implementation has ~10 of them.

```
<CompA onClick={handleClick} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} specificPropA="a" />
<CompB onClick={handleClick} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} specificPropB="b" />
```

Internally, all the components do with the common properties is passing them to a custom hook:

```
const CompA = ({ onClick, onMouseMove, specificPropA }) => {
  useCustomEventHandlingLogic({ onClick, onMouseMove });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // some CompA specific logic with specificPropA
  }, [specificPropA]);

  return <div />;
}
```

```
const CompB = ({ onClick, onMouseMove, specificPropB }) => {
  useCustomEventHandlingLogic({ onClick, onMouseMove });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // some CompB specific logic with specificPropB
  }, [specificPropB]);

  return <div />;
}
```

`useCustomEventHandlingLogic` is a hook that register events into a special event system managed by a WebGL renderer.

I'm trying to find a solution to let all these components accept the common properties without having to repeat the logic on each one.

The simplest solution I can think of would be an higher order component:

```
const withCustomEventHandlingLogic = Component => ({ onClick, onMouseMove, ...props }) => {
  useCustomEventHandlingLogic({ onClick, onMouseMove });

  return <Component {...props} />;
}
const CompAWithEvents = withCustomEventHandlingLogic(CompA);
const CompBWithEvents = withCustomEventHandlingLogic(CompB);
```

But I'd like to know if there are other solutions that don't require to use the HOC pattern in order to keep the React DOM tree cleaner and better integrate with the React Hooks programming pattern.

Comment: Perhaps a more concrete/specific example is in order because as you've described it sounds like `CompA` and `CompB` should two instances of the same component, or there's not an issue that 2 components happen to consume `onClick` and `onMouseMove` props and pass these to a custom hook. Are there any other dependencies within either component on what the `useCustom` hook does/returns?

Comment: `CompA` and `CompB` have completely different implementations, the only shared logic is the call to `useCustom` with the shared props.

Comment: Yeah, then the Higher Order Component seems to be the answer. This doesn't force the children components to consume extra props they don't care about. What makes you think HOCs aren't clean (*or are less clean*)? HOCs and React hooks serve two difference purposes.

Comment: Mostly I was looking for something that wouldn't pollute the tree with extra components,

Comment: Again, calling it pollution implies HOCs have a negative impact. If you don't want to use HOCs then the alternative is to implement the logic in each component that needs the additional behavior. You could use the spread operator to gather up the additional props and pass this props object, i.e. `const CompA = ({ specificPropA, ...props }) => { .... ` and `useCustomEventHandlingLogic(props);`. This is about the minimally invasive and DRY version I can think of.